# Android windows-based emulator for openCV applications?

Tags: android, opencv, emulation

Can you please refer me to a windows-based emulator for android, working with eclipse, that can install properly opencv applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [tutorial](http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-install-opencv-on-android-vm.html) after downloading [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) there's a free version of it you can use

The tutorial is meant for Ubuntu, although it may help

Comment: Thanks, I got genymotion. But how do I install the openCV manager on it? I am trying to use "Use custom Android SDK tools" option but it gets stuck and doesn't respond.